# sql query to get max match on data for given input

Tags: sql, oracle, switch-statement

Based on the given input, need to apply condition to fetch max match score on below table

**MATCH_RULES**

[image]

Examples:

```
if FN=Y&LN=Y&EMAIL=Y&TAX=Y&DOB=Y&MOBILE=Y 
then id=1 and match_score=100

if FN=Y&LN=Y&EMAIL=Y&TAX=N&DOB=N&MOBILE=Y
then id=5 and match_score=40
```

Required to fetch hight match score satisfied record as a result for given input

Comment: the input values will come from UI and if given matches satisfy with rules table then need to get highest match rule row

Answer (score 1):

You could use case when

```
    select case when 
          (FN='Y' AND LN='Y' AND EMAIL ='Y' AND TAX='Y' 
                AND DOB = 'Y' AND MOBILE ='Y') THEN 1 
            when 
           (FN='Y' AND LN='Y' AND EMAIL ='Y' AND TAX='N' 
                AND DOB = 'N'AND MOBILE ='Y') THEN 5 
           end id , 
    case when 
          (FN='Y' AND LN='Y' AND EMAIL ='Y' AND TAX='Y' AND DOB = 'Y' AND MOBILE ='Y') THEN 100
            when 
           (FN='Y' AND LN='Y' AND EMAIL ='Y' AND TAX='N' AND DOB = 'N'AND MOBILE ='Y') THEN 40
           end match_Score       

    from my_table
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL queries you can use the `max()` function to get the maximum value of a column. In your case you can type something like:

```
SELECT max(match_score)
FROM ?
WHERE FN = 'Y' and ...
```